# Powers of $x$ as Chebyshev polynomials

Tags: taylor-expansion, chebyshev-polynomials

I want to convert the first five terms of the Taylor series expansion for $e^x$ into Chebyshev Polynomial, but it requires that I express the power of $x$ as Chebyshev first, I've gotten it up to $x^3$. I got stuck after.

These are the first four... $x^0 =1$, $x=T_0(x)$, $x^2=T_1(x)$, $x^3=\frac{1}{4}(T_3(x)+3T_1(x))$, $x^4 =?$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's two separate questions here. The first is to express $e^x$ as a sum of Chebyshev polynomials, and the second is to determine said Chebyshev polynomials. If all you want is the first, then the simplest thing is to look up the first 5 Chebyshev polynomials (and these can be found easily online.) If you're interested in _finding_ these polynomials, then the usual tools include recurrence relations, orthogonality, the generating function, etc.

Comment: http://www.mhtlab.uwaterloo.ca/courses/me755/web_chap6.pdf

Comment: See "Example: power function expressing through Chebyshev polynomials" in this [text](http://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/dobrush/am34/Mathematica/ch5/chebyshev.html).